# Disappearing horizontally aligned figures spanning 2 columns

Tags: minipage

I am trying to get three figures aligned horizontally (side by side). They are big, so I want them to be visualized across the entire width of the IEEE paper I am writing. Strangely, the following code makes my figures disappear. Please help?

```
%          Template to be used with:
%          spconf.sty  - ICASSP/ICIP LaTeX style file, and
%          IEEEbib.bst - IEEE bibliography style file.
% --------------------------------------------------------------------------

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{spconf,amsmath,graphicx}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{3}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{algorithmic}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{threeparttable}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{changebar}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{media9}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure*}

\begin{minipage}[b]{.3\columnwidth}  
    \centerline{\includegraphics[width=2.5cm]{error_plot_grader1}}
    \centerline{(a)}
\end{minipage}

\hfill

\begin{minipage}[b]{0.3\columnwidth}  
    \centerline{\includegraphics[width=2.5cm]{error_plot_grader2}}
\centerline{(b)}
\end{minipage}

\hfill

\begin{minipage}[b]{0.3\columnwidth}  
    \centerline{\includegraphics[width=2.5cm]{error_plot_inter}}
    \centerline{(c)}
\end{minipage}

\caption{Example of placing a figure with experimental results.}
\label{fig:res}

\end{figure*}

\end{document}
```

Comment: The culprit is `changebar`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently `changebar` is not compatible with `spconf`.

You can use only one of them. If you need `changebar` during manuscript preparation, disable `spconf` until the document is in final form and then reenable it after removing `changebar`.

---

Unrelated, but you won't get three images in a row in that way, because a blank line creates a new paragraph. Use

```
\begin{figure*}

\begin{minipage}[b]{.3\columnwidth}
\centering
\includegraphics[width=2.5cm]{error_plot_grader1}\\
(a)
\end{minipage}\hfill
\begin{minipage}[b]{0.3\columnwidth}
\centering
\includegraphics[width=2.5cm]{error_plot_grader1}\\
(b)
\end{minipage}\hfill
\begin{minipage}[b]{0.3\columnwidth}
\centering
\includegraphics[width=2.5cm]{error_plot_inter}\\
(c)
\end{minipage}

\caption{Example of placing a figure with experimental results.}
\label{fig:res}

\end{figure*}
```

Comment: Wow, thanks! That worked! Yeah, the script is actually correct though. The formatting in my post is wrong.